# Visual studio automaticly in 2 repostitories

Tags: visual-studio, repository

Every time I open a project in visual studio Im in 2 repostitories. One for the repo on github and one called the name of my computer. I wonder why it has not been this way before. And i cant checkout from the ropo named after my pc. If I do i get back to it every time I open visual studio again.

I have tried checked out. But I want to know if there is possible to delete the repo named after my pc.